# How do I add new YouTube video to a new playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Now at the side of a YT video after a search or on someone's account page is the "watch later" button but before you could choose videos and add them to a new playlist instantly; how do I do that because in videos under "Watch later" you can't move specific videos to a new list from there anyway?

Basically, I want to be able to add videos to a playlist in the order I like so I can watch them together later.  I don't want to go to each video's page and then add each of them to the playlist!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from the video player itself, but if you're watching the videos on a Youtube.com page you can add them to an existing playlist or new playlist using the "Add To" button under the video. You'll also have to be logged in to make this button work.

[image]

Comment: So, I can't add videos I haven't even clicked on/watched to a new playlist?  Do you remember how we could before?

Comment: I don't want to do it from the video player but from the video icon one can see when cruising around YT.

Comment: only the watch later list is available from that video icon (believe me... i want this added functionality)

Comment: I wonder why they removed this feature...sigh.

Answer (score 0):

> The best work-around I have got working so far (for desktop) is to
> copy/paste &disable_polymer=1 to the end of your full playlist URL in
> the URL bar, then hit enter to re-load the page.  This will load it
> under the old layout, where the "Add Videos" button is still present.

Taken from google groups forum.